# Run bash source command within a python script

Tags: python, bash

I am using python to run a bash script which contains a bash [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/source-command-in-linux-with-examples/) command. For some reason the `source` command is not working.

Bash script code:

```
#!/bin/bash
SETTINGSFILE=/apps/settings

if test -f "$SETTINGSFILE"; then
  source $SETTINGSFILE  #This is not working
  echo "settings file exists" #reaches here
else
  echo "settings file not found"
fi
...
```

Python code:

```
import subprocess

rc = subprocess.call(["./<name-of-bash-script>.sh"])
```

Basically, I want to run the command `source /apps/settings` using a script. The control reaches to the echo statement (marked with comment), but still `source` command is not executed by the bash script. How to get it working?

Comment: When you say "not executed" do you mean not executed in your parent process running the python code? It is probably the case that python opens subprocess, runs /bin/bash, sources your file, and then closes that subprocess. Nothing in that list sources the current parent process.

Comment: So, I tried running the bash script on its own without calling it from python as well. That did not work either.

Comment: Ya, that didn't do anything you just switch your parent process (python) to another shell. I would think your shabang line is opening a new bash shell subprocess. I believe if you remove the /bin/bash shabang line and then source that file in the shell it will work fine.

Comment: Does not work after removing shabang as well.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change with "source $SETTINGSFILE"?

Comment: It sets the system resources, paths and other things that are needed later in the program.

Comment: If the "source $SETTINGSFILE" command sets environment variables, those changes only exist inside the (sub-)shell created by subprocess, they will be lost when you exit the subprocess call and return to your python process.

Comment: You can't meaningfully `source` a bash script from python. The entire point of `source` is to run the script directly in the parent process, rather than as a subprocess. But you can't run a bash script directly in python, because it's bash, not python; you can only run it as a subprocess.

Comment: @MaharashiRawal : If `source` does not run the file at all for whatever reason, it gives at least an error message. It certainly does not silently skip the file. Didn't you try to turn on `set -x` to see what's going on?

Comment: @user1934428 Hey, I tried with that, so apparently the file does execute, but does not do what it intends to. I am trying to set Python version to be 3 incase it is set to 2 through the settings file. If I run source command directly from the terminal, it works, but when I run it through my script, it doesn't. Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: @joao, Yes, from `set -x`, I figured the `source` command is executed in subshell (++). Is there anyway I can get it to run in the parent shell?

Comment: So, figured out a way to set the variables in the same parent shell, I now run the script as `. ./script-name.sh`. But, still trying to figure out how to get the desired result by running this script in python.

Comment: @MaharashiRawal: `source` is definitiley **not** running in a "subshell", but in the sourcing process. This is the whole point of using this command. Your whole script is, of course, executed as a child process from Python. Maybe you should make your mind clear, on which processes are involved here and what you want to achieve exactly.... And, please, put additional information into a comment, but amend it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why running "source file.sh" in a terminal would not load your environment variables (I am not on a linux system right now and can't really test this). However, in general, if you want to manipulate your environment, you should do that directly in python and not call a child process. For example,

```
import os
os.environ['THING'] = 'WORD'
```

I believe if you wish to change your environment variables from a child process then you need to imbed that child process in your current parent process (so that you become the child with the new environment) and you need to keep that child process open (you don't want it to terminate). You probably need something like "/bin/bash -i" at the end of your source file (to keep the subprocess running). You then need to use something like the pexpect module to imbed subprocess in current process.

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('file.sh')
child.interact()
#check your os.environ to see if it is updated from your source file.
```

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: I never worked with `pexpect`, but I'm pretty sure that in your code, it runs the shell, which is specified in the #! line of `file.sh`, in a **child process**. The parent process (Python) just acts as a tty for the shell process and can monitor its output and feed to its input.